# interactive session eval and tf.random_uniform do not produce expected output

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a problem with the following code piece, the `obs_pattern`, `obs_seq` and `obs_seq_s` do not produce the expected behavior. I tried with TensorFlow 1.2.1. I suspect there is something wrong.

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
seq_length = 5
num_bits = 4
obs_pattern_shape = [num_bits, seq_length]
obs_pattern = tf.cast(
    tf.random_uniform(obs_pattern_shape, minval=0, maxval=2, seed=1234, dtype=tf.int32), 
    tf.float32)
print(obs_pattern.eval())
seq_length_zeros = tf.zeros([1, seq_length])
obs_seq = tf.concat([obs_pattern, seq_length_zeros], axis=0)
print(obs_seq.eval())
add_vec = tf.one_hot([num_bits], (num_bits + 1), on_value = 1.0, off_value=0.0, axis=0)
obs_seq_s = tf.concat([obs_seq, add_vec], axis=1)
print(obs_seq_s.eval())

sess.close()
```

obs_pattern

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

obs_seq

```
[[ 1.  1.  0.  1.  1.]
[ 0.  1.  1.  0.  1.]
[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
[ 1.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

obs_seq_s

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

**EDIT:** 
Based on the comment below I changed obs_pattern and it behaves as I'd thought

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(2, size=(num_bits, seq_length))
obs_pattern = tf.convert_to_tensor(arr, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected each time you run sess on a tensor formed with obs_pattern it reruns a new random uniform.
To get the behavior you expect generate **ONCE** a numpy array with numpy then feed it to a placeholder of the same shape : obs_pattern.
To clarify you used a seed **but** you ran the op a number of times so you get the first iterates of the sequence.